# Do the French tax authorities require French Forms 5000 and 5002 to be original, or can they be copies/scans?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, france, tax-treaty

I wonder whether [French Form 5000](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf) ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/1qClF),  [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805233357/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf)) a.k.a. CERFA 5000 and  [French Form 5002](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5002EN-2.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181118082931/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5002EN-2.pdf)) a.k.a. CERFA 5002 need to be original when sent to the French tax authorities (a.k.a. the Fisc), or whether they can be copies/scans. I went through the [Form 5000 instructions](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/NOTICE_5000_EN-2.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181118142544/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/NOTICE_5000_EN-2.pdf)) but couldn't see the information. I'd like my US financial institution to seal it in the US, and scanning would save time+money.

I file my French tax forms online. Forms 5000 and 5002 are however sent  by my French financial institution: I wonder whether French tax authorities require my French financial institution Forms 5000 and 5002  to be original paper versions.

Comment: do you file your French tax return online or by paper submission? {lease [edit] your question to make it clear. If you have an online account with the fisc, there is a facility to ask the question directly online. Mostly, in France, you generally file tax records "sur l'honneur"  ie on your honour and unless the form is provided (as in the case of cerfa 3916 - declaring bank accounts) if the fisc require verification of the figures submitted they will ask for them.

Comment: @24601 thanks, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal experience as a French resident, in such circumstances, since forms/information are submitted *sur l'honneur* a facsimile of a form correctly completed and signed would be regarded as a substantive submission.

To be certain, you must keep the originals for a long time in case they are needed for inspection later.

You can refer to [this reference](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/A15346?xtor=EPR-100&lang=en) (in English) which is a simulator from the French Government about the keeping of documents and the length of time to do so.

[This additional reference](https://www.frenchentree.com/living-in-france/employment/paperwork-how-long-do-i-keep-it/) is a further useful reference in this regard. The reference suggests 4 years for tax records after which they can be destroyed but the over-riding principal is always - *if in doubt - keep it*.